# RequestBody and camel case request parameters

Tags: spring, spring-rest

I have an endpoint with a request body:

```java
 @PostMapping("/v1/message")
  @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.isAnyClientId(@authorizeConfig.getIds())")
  public void receive(
      @RequestBody @NotNull @Valid final Message message,
      @RequestHeader final HttpHeaders headers) {
    ...
  }
```

The `Message` class has several parameters:

```java
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic = true)
public class Message {

  @NotBlank(message = "tenant is empty")
  private String tenant;

  @NotBlank(message = "messageId is empty")
  private String messageId;

  @NotBlank(message = "payload is empty")
  private String payload;

  @NotNull(message = "messageType is empty")
  private MessageType messageType;

  private String xSchemaVersion;
}
```

When I perform a request to that endpoint:

```json
{
   "tenant":"client1",
   "messageId":"670f13e15d554b2bba56f6d76d33b79c",
   "payload":"",
   "messageType":"MessageType.Email",
   "xSchemaVersion":"2.7.3"
}
```

I get the following error:

```json
{
    "status": 400,
    "date": "2022-07-18T08:21:21.430+0000",
    "exception": "missing parameter: xSchemaVersion",
    "description": "uri=/v1/message"
}
```

But if I do the following instead:

```json
{
   "tenant":"client1",
   "messageId":"670f13e15d554b2bba56f6d76d33b79c",
   "payload":"",
   "messageType":"MessageType.Email",
   "xschemaVersion":"2.7.3"
}
```

I get `200 OK`.

Notice that the only thing I changed is the lowercase `s` in `xschemaVersion` instead of `xSchemaVersion`.

Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `lomboks` getter & setter for your `Message` entity.

If you check, lombok will generate get & set for your `xSchemaVersion` as
`getXSchemaVersion()` & `setXSchemaVersion(..)`, which is quite different than what any IDE would automatically generate for us.

If I use eclipse for generating getters & setters for `xSchemaVersion` it would be `getxSchemaVersion()` & `setxSchemaVersion(..)`; and this is what spring is also looking for as valid getter & setter for field `xSchemaVersion` (based on reflaction).

Because lombok is making your `x` & `s` as an upper case, spring is unable to map your `xSchemaVersion` with input if you use `xSchemaVersion`.

The reason it works with `xschemaVersion` because, spring is able to map field as it does lowecase conversion for words after get & set( `getXSchemaVersion()` & `setXSchemaVersion(..)`.)

Workaround -- create separate getter & setter in your `Message` for `xSchemaVersion` as `getxSchemaVersion` & `setxSchemaVersion(..)` which acts as  overriding methods of default generated getter /setter of lombok.

Once you do this, you can successfully able to use `xSchemaVersoin` in your input.

Comment: Thank you. That's it. I solved the problem by annotating the field with `@JsonProperty("xSchemaVersion")`.

Answer (score 0):

According to Project Lombok https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter

you can add AccessLevel.PRIVATE to the GETTER SETTER for not used field.

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE) @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE) String xSchemaVersion;
```